# Transitioning between 3 background colours

Tags: android, xml, performance

Currently, I'm using a the following to transfer between 2 background colours:

> background_Transition.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- TODO: HIGHER FPS, may require programmatic transitioning -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_start" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_end" />
</transition>
```

> background_start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

> background_end.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/background_end" />
</shape>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
...
// fade from start to end 
backgroundTransition.startTransition(DURATION);
// fade from current state to other state (used to fade from end to start)
backgroundTransition.reverseTransition(DURATION);
...
```

---

I have 3 issues with this solution.

1. As you may have noticed from the `TODO:` comment, the FPS is really low on this transition.
2. It can only transfer between 2 states; I now wish to transfer between a third.
3. The `reverseTransition` method of the `Transition` class doesn't idempotently work, like `startTransition` does. It flips the state of the transition. I wan't to be able to idempotently transition to either of N states of the transition.

Comment: You'd need to define what you mean by 3 states.  DO you want it to go from A->B->C in one animation?  Why not just have the end of your first animation trigger a 2nd one then?

Comment: No. I mean a single transition between 2 of *n* different states. *n* choose 2 different possible transitions

Comment: You'd need to do that in code. The animation resource language doesn't allow parameterized animations

Comment: Meaning I'll have to manually interpolate the colours between the two, and then set an interval for setting the background colour?

Comment: You could probably get away with writing an animation class that takes the parameters for start and end in a method call and then runs the animation with those values. All of this xml had a parallel java class hierarchy you can subclass